# Absolute entropy of methane at 111 K

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, combustion

I have to analyse a combustion process. One of the inputs of the process is methane at 1 bar and 111 K. To apply the second law of themodynamics I have to calculate $\overline{s}(111 K, 1 bar)$. By considering methane as an ideal gas I can use the following equation:

$$\overline{s}(T, p) = \overline{s}^o(T) - \overline{R}\ln\left(\frac{p}{p_{ref}}\right)$$

As the input pressure is equal to $p_{ref}$, the logarithmic term vanishes and I only need $\overline{s}^o(111K)$.

From tabular data I can obtain $\overline{s}^o(298K)$, but I have not find a table for obtaining $\overline{s}^o(111K)$.

Is there any equation to calculate $\overline{s}^o(T)$ from $\overline{s}^o(T_{ref})$? Or is it necessary to use a table?

Comment: Do you know Cp as a function of T in the range of interest?

Comment: I have found $c_p$(100K) = 33,28 J/mol.K and $c_p$(298K) = 35,69 J/mol.K. I can interpolate these values and use $c_p$ constant because the analysis is just an exercise. Can I use TdS equations for finding $\overline{s}^o(298K)$ - $\overline{s}^o(111K)$?

Comment: At constant pressure, $dS=\frac{C_p}{T}dT$ for an ideal gas.

Comment: Would you write an answer so I can accept? If you prefer, I can write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal gas at constant pressure, $$dS=\frac{C_p}{T}dT$$